# Date time index sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, indexing

I know this is a common topic but i stil feel my scenario requires some custom advice. I was selecting from a table the other day and it took me an AGE to select on a datetime column that has not been indexed. I want to index this, only problem ebing is that the "production" 2005 box i am unfamiliar with and how it will handle the index creation. With that in mind i am wondering what the safest way for me to create an index on the table is. All the details i think people will need are below (i hope) :

Index to be created on field 5 (possibly field4 also)

Table 1 definition:

```
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TABLE 1](
[ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT [DF_BLA]  DEFAULT (newid()),
[field1] [nvarchar](7) NULL,
[field2] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
[field3] [nvarchar](2) NULL,
[field4] [datetime] NULL,
[field5] [datetime] NULL,
[field6] [smallint] NULL,
[field7] [nvarchar](1) NULL,
[field8] [nvarchar](7) NULL,
[field9] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
[field10] [smallint] NULL,
[field11] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
[field12] [datetime] NULL,
     CONSTRAINT [PK_ID] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
     (
[ID] ASC
      )WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,      ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
      ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Total count of rows in Table 1 : 2926836

Comment: What are your concerns when you ask about the *safest* way to create an index on the table is? Realistically 3m rows is not that many so index creation should not take more than a couple of minutes, so if you can find a period in the day when the table won't be in use for a few minutes then you can create the index without many worries, alternatively if you are using the Enterprise edition of sql server you can create the index online, meaning the table can still be used while the index is created.

Comment: On an unrelated note having a [GUID as a clustering key is not a very good idea](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/), at the very least you should use `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` for the default.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry for the late response. I should be able to create the index online. Just hope there is enough space!!!

Comment: On the GUID note the design decision was taken before my arrival possibly about 5 years ago i think. Not sure if it would be a good idea for me to start changing the clustering key. Like everything downtime is not an option. Its not THAT bad is it? I have read the article you linked to but my understanding was that it shouldn't cause any harm in its current state.